# Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar issue

Tags: android

In my application I'm using `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

My style is like :

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    </style>
```

the problem is that the menu is transparent, and i need  to change it

-[Image1](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=2a180a4fdf5c8c6f&id=2A180A4FDF5C8C6F!741&v=3&ithint=photo,PNG&authkey=!ANBXpdP6fmuRgtw)

[Image2](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=2A180A4FDF5C8C6F!740&authkey=!ABYvF5mGqtiMf4o&v=3&ithint=photo%2Cpng)

Comment: could you please attach an image for better understanding?

Comment: can you give me your Email and i well send you the image , i do not have 10 reputation

Comment: you mean the problem is the background of menu is transparent and you don't want it ?

Comment: it should be "android:Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" or "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

Comment: yes i dont want  it like this